# Type Inference support for Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference

I try to use Compiler API to process JavaScript code and use Type inference to predict types of 'object' in a 'object.property' PropertyAccessExpression node.
Simple ones like first sample blow worked fine, but most examples failed, wonder if this is intentional way of using TypeScript type inference for, or because of I did not write proper code? Thank you!

```
var obj={prop: ''};
var h=obj;
h.prop = ''; //works! 'h' show as 'obj' type

function fx(arg) {return arg;}
var i=fx(obj);
i.prop = ''; //failed! type of 'i' show 'any', it should be 'obj'
```

Below is source code using checker to print inferred type:

```
var ts = require('typescript');
function visit(node) {
    ts.forEachChild(node, visit);
    console.log( checker.getSymbolAtLocation(node.name));
}

var program = ts.createProgram([process.argv[2]], {lib: ['DOM'], allowJs: true, target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES5, module: ts.ModuleKind.None});
var checker = program.getTypeChecker();
ts.forEachChild(program.getSourceFiles()[0], visit);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your function returns `any` so `i` is of type `any`, too. Also `i` never can be of type `obj` only of type `{prop: string}`.

You can make your function a generic function:

```
function fx<T>(arg: T): T {return arg;}
var i=fx(obj);
```

In this case `i` is of Type `{prop: string}`.

Comment: No, 'i' should be 'obj'... ...only if the inference engine analyzes 'fx()' return statement and 'fx(obj)' call from the code. BTW, I am processing arbitrary legitimate JavaScript code, so I can change my code to adapt for the input source, not the other way around.

Comment: Have you tried to make your function generic? What type did you get?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot change to generic function as you suggested: 1) I take valid JavaScript input to infer types, the generic function code in your response is not even valid Javascript syntax. 2) I have no control on what input I get except for it's valid Javascript code.

Comment: Do you know how deep TypeScript compiler would go to infer types for Javascript? For example, does it analyze function return and function calls to predict all possible types, and processing all use-define expressions?